# T4MVC not picking up the Views in Areas (ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

T4MVC is working fine everywhere except in Areas.

In Areas, it picks up the Controllers and the Actions, but not the Views.

So, I cannot write, in my controller:

```
return View(MVC.MyArea.MyController.Views.MyView);
```

Outside of the Areas, I CAN write:

```
return View(Views.MyOtherView);
```

I can also refer to actions in my area controllers:

```
MVC.MyArea.MyController.MyAction()
```

In other words:

a. I can get anything I want, if it is not in an Area.

b. I can get at the Actions in my Area controllers.

c. But I CANNOT get my Views in my Area.

What could the problem be?

TIA

### EDIT:

The issue is getting T4MVC to rerun (see David Ebbo's answer and my "answer").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my issue is being caused by T4MVC not rerunning.  As a result (I speculate) the T4MVC does not update to reflect changes in your project.  For example, changing the parameters of an Action in a Controller.  Or (specific to this question) adding a new View.

The T4MVC documentation on getting itself to rerun is vague, but points you at a VS add in called Chirpy.

Chirpy installs, and then you have to go in an configure it.  You do this by opening Visual Studio, then going to Tools >> Options and choosing the Chirpy option.

See the image:

[image]

I had to add the template name T4MVC.tt bit to get it to work.  Not sure if this is necessary or why.  But it all now works fine.

If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work, and I verified it by:

- Creating a new MVC3 app and adding the latest T4MVC 2.6.40 (via nuget)
- Adding an Area named MyArea
- Adding a controller named MyController
- Adding a view named MyView
- Make sure you rerun the T4MVC.tt custom tool

After that, I'm able to write:

```
namespace Mvc3Application.Areas.MyArea.Controllers {
    public partial class MyController : Controller {
        public virtual ActionResult Index() {
            return View(Views.MyView);
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
namespace Mvc3Application.Areas.MyArea.Controllers {
    public partial class MyController : Controller {
        public virtual ActionResult Index() {
            return View(MVC.MyArea.My.Views.MyView);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the second case, the token in 'My' instead of 'MyController', which is the way it always works.

Please try following those steps in a clean app to see if it works.

Comment: yes, that works.  What also worked with my original project was uninstalling and reinstalling the t4mvc package (I already had version 2.6.40 installed, so not a version issue).  So it seems as if the template didn't rerun automatically.  What can I do to force this?